# From a table, concatenate values in a cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've never done this before, but I was wondering is it possible using a table to concatenate values into a cell?

Here (see pic below) I have a list of orders, but the orders come in different rows, which makes it difficult to see what customers are ordering before we finalized their order.

The list add can be infinitely long, with customers ordering several items.

[image]

In the first pic, Joe ordered 2 items, but his second item appears in the 5th row, which sometimes gets overlooked, and gets missed.

I was wondering is it possible to somehow merge this into one cell, where the end result would look something like this?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Did you mean "2-Joe-To-Go Biscuit, Bagle"?

Comment: is it possible with vba? Yes it is possible.

Comment: Yes that correct @GSerg

Comment: Just sort the table on order number before taking actions on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're sheet names are or the columns you are using so you'll probably have to change a bunch of values but this should do what you're trying to accomplish.

```
Sub combinecells()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With Sheet2 'Change to your sheet name
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Change to column where your data starts
        For i = 2 To lr
            If Not dict.exists(.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                dict.Add .Cells(i, 1).Value, .Cells(i, 2).Value & "-" & .Cells(i, 3).Value & vbNewLine & .Cells(i, 4).Value
            Else
                dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value) = dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value) & ", " & .Cells(i, 4).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    With Sheet3 'Change to your sheet name
        Dim key As Variant
        i = 2
        .cells(1, 1).value = "Combined Order"
        For Each key In dict
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = key & "-" & dict(key)
            i = i + 1
        Next key
    End With
End Sub
```